# Retrofit connection time out with http

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, okhttp

hi I'm trying to connect my android client to my server with **retrofit** and **okhttp3** but I have a problem in retrofit I should add a base URL but when the URL has **SSL (https://)** it's working flawlessly but when I want to do the **exact job without SSL (http://)** sometimes i have timeout error (5 times in 10 times) I really can't understand the problem my backend is a **Symfony** framework and its working with or without SSL on my **phone browser** and on my **computer browser** or **Postman** application this is my retrofit client:

```
public class apiClient {
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
private static final String CACHE_CONTROL = "Cache-Control";

public static Retrofit initClient(){
    String text = "";
    byte[] data = android.util.Base64.decode(apiClient.retrofit_id, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
    try {
        text = new String(data, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(text)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    return retrofit;
}
public static  void setClient(retrofit2.Response<ApiResponse> response, Activity activity, PrefManager prf){
    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
        if (response.body().getCode().equals(202)) {
            Toasty.error(activity, response.body().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            SplashActivity.adapteActivity(activity);
        } else {
            prf.setString("formatted","true");
        }
    }
}
public static String LoadClientData(Activity activity){
   return activity.getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
}
public static void FormatData(final Activity activity,Object o){
    try {
        final PrefManager prf = new PrefManager(activity.getApplication());
        if (!prf.getString("formatted").equals("true")) {
            if (apiClient.check(activity)) {
                Retrofit retrofit=apiClient.initClient();
                apiRest service = retrofit.create(apiRest.class);
                Call<ApiResponse> callback = service.setWallpaper(apiClient.LoadClientData(activity));
                callback.enqueue(new Callback<ApiResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ApiResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<ApiResponse> response) {
                        apiClient.setClient(response,activity,prf);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ApiResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        if (o!=null){
            return;
        }else{

        }
    }
}
public static boolean check(Activity activity){
    final PrefManager prf = new PrefManager(activity.getApplication());
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String strDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());

    if (prf.getString("LAST_DATA_LOAD").equals("")) {
        prf.setString("LAST_DATA_LOAD", strDate);
    } else {
        String toyBornTime = prf.getString("LAST_DATA_LOAD");
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        try {
            Date oldDate = dateFormat.parse(toyBornTime);
            System.out.println(oldDate);

            Date currentDate = new Date();

            long diff = currentDate.getTime() - oldDate.getTime();
            long seconds = diff / 1000;

            if (seconds >15) {
                prf.setString("LAST_DATA_LOAD", strDate);
                return  true;
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return  false;
}
public static Retrofit getClient() {
    if (retrofit==null) {
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                .addInterceptor( provideHttpLoggingInterceptor() )
                .addInterceptor( provideOfflineCacheInterceptor() )
                .addNetworkInterceptor( provideCacheInterceptor() )
                .cache( provideCache() )
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();

        OkHttp3Downloader okHttp3Downloader = new OkHttp3Downloader(okHttpClient);
        Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(App.getInstance())
                .downloader(okHttp3Downloader)
                .build();
        Picasso.setSingletonInstance(picasso);

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Config.BASE_URL)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
private static Cache provideCache ()
{
    Cache cache = null;
    try
    {
        cache = new Cache( new File( App.getInstance().getCacheDir(), "wallpaper-cache" ),
                10 * 1024 * 1024 ); // 10 MB
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Timber.e( e, "Could not create Cache!" );
    }
    return cache;
}
private static HttpLoggingInterceptor provideHttpLoggingInterceptor ()
{
    HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor =
            new HttpLoggingInterceptor( new HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger()
            {
                @Override
                public void log (String message)
                {
                    Timber.d( message );
                }
            } );
    httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel( BuildConfig.DEBUG ? HEADERS : NONE );
    return httpLoggingInterceptor;
}
public static Interceptor provideCacheInterceptor ()
{
    return new Interceptor()
    {
        @Override
        public Response intercept (Chain chain) throws IOException
        {
            Response response = chain.proceed( chain.request() );

            // re-write response header to force use of cache
            CacheControl cacheControl = new CacheControl.Builder()
                    .maxAge( 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS )
                    .build();

            return response.newBuilder()
                    .header( CACHE_CONTROL, cacheControl.toString() )
                    .build();
        }
    };
}
public static String retrofit_id = "aHR0cDovL2xpY2Vuc2UucmlzdGFuYS5jb20vYXBpLw==";
public static Interceptor provideOfflineCacheInterceptor ()
{
    return new Interceptor()
    {
        @Override
        public Response intercept (Chain chain) throws IOException
        {
            Request request = chain.request();

            if ( !App.hasNetwork() )
            {
                CacheControl cacheControl = new CacheControl.Builder()
                        .maxStale( 30, TimeUnit.DAYS )
                        .build();

                request = request.newBuilder()
                        .cacheControl( cacheControl )
                        .build();
            }

            return chain.proceed( request );
        }
    };
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add Network Security Config to allow non-ssl connections. https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config